# How to add shared or static library using PyTorch C++ extension?

Tags: c++, pytorch, shared-libraries, static-libraries, pybind11

How do I use `torch.utils.cpp_extension.load` to link shared or static library from external source?

I wrote some function in C++, and am using it in PyTorch. So I am using `load` function from `torch.utils.cpp_extension` to load a [PyTorch C++ extension just-in-time (JIT)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cpp_extension.html).

This is the `wrapper.py` file's content:

```py
import os
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

my_func = load(name='my_func', sources=[os.path.join(dir_path, 'my_func.cpp')], extra_cflags=['-fopenmp', '-O2'], extra_ldflags=['-lgomp','-lrt'])
```

`my_func.cpp` uses OpenMP, so I use the above flags.

Now, I am trying to additionally use several functions in [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) library in `my_func.cpp`. After cloning and `make`ing zstd repository, shared libraries like `libzstd.so`, `libzstd.so.1`, `libzstd.so.1.5.3`, and static library like `libzstd.a` have been created.

I've included `#include <zstd.h>` inside `my_func.cpp` and used zstd's functions.

I now have to modify `wrapper.py` to tell the compiler that I am using functions from zstd library.

How can I successfully compile `my_func.cpp` using PyTorch C++ extension's `torch.utils.cpp_extension.load` -- which arguments should I modify? Or, is it even possible to add external shared or static library using this method?

Frankly, I'm not familiar with the difference between static and shared library. But it seems that I can compile `my_func.cpp` with either one of them, i.e., `g++ -fopenmp -O2 -lgomp -lrt -o my_func my_func.cpp lib/libzstd.so.1.5.3` and `g++ -fopenmp -O2 -lgomp -lrt -o my_func my_func.cpp lib/libzstd.a` both works.

I just can't figure out how I can do the exact same compiling using `torch.utils.cpp_extension.load`.

Sorry for delivering kind of a lengthy question. I just wanted to make things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. `extra_ldflags` argument in `torch.utils.cpp_extension.load` can handle this. In my case, I've added `libzstd.so` file in my repository and added `-lzstd` in above argument.